# Let $a, b$ integers such that $ab+2a+3b=93$. Find all solutions integers.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Let $a, b$ integers such that $ab+2a+3b=93$. Find all solutions integers.

What I tried is
$ab+2a+3b=b(a+3)+2a$ but i don't see how to proceed to related $a$ and $b$ such that see it multiplying and play with combinations of  $93=3*13$.

Comment: There are 12 integer solutions : https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ab+%2B2a+%2B+3b+%3D+93   :)              ( 93 = 3 * 31 ;) )

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: Hint: If $ab+2a+3b=93$, then $(a+3)(b+2)=?$

Comment: $$93 = 3 . 31 $$ not $$93 =3 . 13$$ as you said.

Answer (score 3):

$(a+3)(b+2)=99$

then you can decompose 99 and get integer solutions.